# View the history of a file that got renamed

Tags: github

I committed a file a few times, then renamed it and committed. How to view the history of it prior to its renaming?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope there is a better way, but here is one solution (click on red rectangles):

[image]

[image]

[image]